# Twitter bootstrap modal fade black

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal,when I click the link,still black fade appears on the modal.

FYI - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtY1pLdmVsclpQXzA/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Signin</a></li>

    </ul>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162105/1379394):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sfWBT/1/)

**NOTE: when you want to hide the fade black just remove `backdrop: true;` from the jquery.**

HTML:

```
<div id="event-modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
        <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some information</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn primary" href="#">Primary</a>
        <a class="btn secondary" href="#">Secondary</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="/events/2-fefewfewfe/rsvps" data-backdrop="true" data-controls-modal="event-modal" data-keyboard="true">I'm attending!<span class="ico join"></span></a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
    $('#event-modal').modal({
        backdrop: true
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#event-modal {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like CSS issue.
Check if something doesn't overwrite your modal `z-index` property, by default modal has:

```
.modal {
   z-index: 1050;
}
```

And backdrop:

```
.modal-backdrop {
   z-index: 1040;
}
```

Modal should have higher value.

Answer (score 0):

Same code working fine for me.. Check your JS files were added properly or not..

> Esp. bootstrap-modal.js, bootstrap-transition.js

check once this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7vyUQ/

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Signin</a></li>

    </ul>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do i have to include separately for bootstrap-modal.js and bootstrap-transition.js ? i've include only bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.css