# bootstrap modal backdrop is not disappearing when we click anywhere in screen with print window

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using print button on bootstrap modal,

The problem is modal backdrop is not disappearing once I click any other area of screen **when print window is open.**

It works perfectly when **we close print window** then click any other area of screen.

for better understanding you can see this image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctWPQ.jpg]

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openWin()
            {
                var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
                myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

                myWindow.document.close();
                myWindow.focus();
                myWindow.print();
                myWindow.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Modal Example</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your issue is same as here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874225/twitter-bootstrap-modal-fade-black

Answer (score 0):

Use 
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
Within the **openWin** function