# Modal Fade Class stops Modal Start

Tags: jquery, css, .net

Issue:
When I remove `*class="modal fade"*` my code works in the fact that it appears, though the buttons don't function (I'm hoping it's the Class issue that is faulting the code)

Notes:
The code is designed to pop up, as per a modal, on page load. I've included code for the aspx, .aspx.vb and the specific CSS code for the "modal fade".

Code:

**.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Dashboard1.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Dashboard1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openModal() {
                $('#StartModal').modal('show');
            }
        </script>


        <div class="modal fade" id="StartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myStartModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog700" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <button type="button" class="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="x">Welcome</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Welcome to the Test.</p>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <br />
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <br />
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Start</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    Some random text on the main page
</body>
</html>
```

**.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _Dashboard1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        '#####///Launch start script modal
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Pop", "openModal();", True)
        '#####\\\Launch start script modal

    End Sub

End Class
```

CSS Code Sample (bootstrap.min.css)

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    outline: 0;
}

    .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out;
        transition: transform .3s ease-out;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,-25%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,-25%);
        -o-transform: translate(0,-25%);
        transform: translate(0,-25%);
    }

    .modal.in .modal-dialog {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
        -o-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Research:

[Bootstrap modal: class="modal fade" causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199847/bootstrap-modal-class-modal-fade-causing-problems)

[Twitter bootstrap: modal fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146996/twitter-bootstrap-modal-fade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe this to be an asp problem and not a jQuery one, as the most probable answer is the script fires before the modal is loaded on the page~

Pobably

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
  $('#StartModal').modal('show');
});
```

is your answer.

Comment: Probably correct, Ironically though, that makes it a jQuery problem....not an asp problem ie the jQuery is called prior to the loading of the page.

Comment: But it does, as he enqued the script with asp , and it should be enqued on page load instead on page creation.. well if asp has such a function. i'm a php developer. Also i dont seem to get the correct spelling of probable no matter how many years have passed...

Comment: Where am I putting this, I tried before and after   $('#StartModal').modal('show');

Comment: I see your perspective, though the OP can just change `function openModal() { $('#StartModal').modal('show');  }` to `$(function(){$('#StartModal').modal('show'); })` as you mentioned and avoid having to call the function at all since they want it to appear on load

Comment: Thanks, again works before I add modal fade back in.

Comment: remove the enque script and just replace your function with this piece of code, it should work.

Comment: @Elentriel I have it as  <script type="text/javascript">  function openModal() {   $(document).ready(function () {               $('#StartModal').modal('show');   });  }  </script> I assume I need to keep the openModal part otherwise it will not be launched from the dashboard1.aspx.vb page ( I will not always want to launch)

Comment: i'm not particularly knowledgable about asp though, but it shouldn't matter if you enque the script or just throwing it from the page to the client? Thats how php would work at least (also by now i believe you should update your title and tags)